# toString method with adjustable Array size

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

Every source I've looked at I either don't understand, doesn't seem to apply, or uses something like an Array list.  I'm not familiar with those.  So I'd like to use a basic toString method that prints out the index of the array as well as the number held when compared to the variable 'length' -- num.length could be different as that's the physical size of the underlying array.  The for loop at the bottom has the gist of it.  I'm trying to print out the index (0-infinite) with int's that are held in the resizeable array.  The variable 'length' is not the actual size of the array but a working size that contains 0 until another cell is added.  The 'strang' variable is just something I've tried.  I don't think it will work, but anything else I doesn't seem to help as I'm stuck.

```
public class XArray
{
    private int[] nums;
    private int length;

    public XArray()
    {
        nums = new int[10];
        length = 0;
    }

    public void add(int value)
    {
        if (length == nums.length)
        {
            int[] nums2 = new int[(int)(nums.length * 1.2)];
            for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
            {
                nums2[i] = nums[i];
            }
            nums = nums2;
        }
        nums[length] = value;
        length++;
    }

    public void set(int index, int value)
    {
        if (index < length)
        {
            nums[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public int get(int index)
    {
        return nums[index];
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return length;
    }

    public void remove()
    {
        nums[length - 1] = 0;
        length--;
    }

    public String toString(int[] nums)
    {
        String strang = "l";
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < length; i++ )
        {
            strang = "Index: " + i + " Number: " + nums[i] + ", ";
        }
        return strang;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the values on each iteration of the loop...something like...

```
public String toString(int[] nums)
{
    StringBuilder strang = new StringBuilder(length);
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < length; i++ )
    {
        strang.append("Index: ").append(i).append(" Number: ").append(nums[i]).append(", ");
    }
    return strang.toString();
}
```

Generally speaking, `toString` should't take parameters, there would a difference between `nums` and `length` which could cause issues

```
@Override
public String toString() {...
```

This way, you will be printing the contents of the objects `num` array, which is contextually associated with `length`

Comment: Using this method how would I call it?  I'm using BlueJ

XArray nums = new XArray();
nums.add(0);
nums.add(1); .....
nums.toString(int [] nums) ?   Also, adding @Override just before the method gives me an error saying that it does not implement or override a method from a supertype

Comment: All Objects have a `toString` method, make sure that you have removed the parameters.  You can call `toString` directly or indirectly.  `System.out.println(nums);` or `System.out.println(nums.toString());` depending on your needs

Comment: Yeah, I needed to remove the parameters.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to use `+=` instead of `=` in that method (though many people will tell you to use a `StringBuilder` because successive concatenations, if not optimized by a compiler` will generate a lot of garbage).

Also, don't pass in `nums`! You want to use the field `nums`; passing in an argument will use the argument. The *real* `toString` has no parameters (and should have an `@Override` annotation).

Comment: FYI `strang` is a `String`, I also believe that the OP may have an array which `n` in size, but may only contain `length` valid entries, so `Arrays.toString(nums)` would print ALL the elements, not just the one's that a valid, from the perspective of the class, just saying

Comment: Ha, didn't know I could use += for strings, but it makes sense.

Not sure about the field nums vs argument...Ah maybe I do.  So I should leave it as toString() instead.

I'll take a look at Arrays.toString(strang); but I've never used it.

MadProgrammer is correct about 'length' not being the actual length.

Comment: @dsorenson I don't think `Arrays.toString(nums)` is correct because if nums was an array of size 20 but you only truly added 6 values, then `Arrays.toString` would write out too many.

Comment: Okay, I won't use it in this case.